# Spring Cloud Netflix: Whats happening in ZuulConfiguration with the ZuulServlet?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Looking in [ZuulConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulConfiguration.java), I see the following:

```
@Bean
public ZuulController zuulController() {
    return new ZuulController();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean zuulServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new ZuulServlet(),
            this.zuulProperties.getServletPattern());
}
```

[ZuulController](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/web/ZuulController.java) wraps the ZuulServlet and manages its lifecycle as if it were a Spring Controller.  What throws me is that the ZuulConfiguration class registers the servlet anyways using a ServletRegistrationBean.  Perhaps I am thinking the wrong thing, but I would think that you would do one or the other.  Could someone explain why both are necessary?

Using this configuration, is the ZuulServlet running as a true servlet (known by the embedded servlet container), a controller (which delegates to the servlet) or both?

Thanks,

Joshua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/0391cfff6590478abc97253ef676589e6545a06a):

**Allow streaming of multipart requests in Zuul proxy**

It turns out that the suckiness of Zuul with multipart requests
comes almost entirely from the Multipart handling in Spring's
DispatcherServlet. This change makes the proxy routes available
on an alternative path /zuul/ (where
/zuul is the default value of zuul.servletPath). I have
tested those with 800MB file uploads using the main method in
the FormZuulServletProxyApplicationTests and the main
observation is that there is no OutOfMemory error (no-one tries
to download the complete request body). It works with Ribbon
and with the simple (HttpClient) filter. With Ribbon you
will need to set some timeouts if you want to upload files
as large as that, e.g. see application.yml in the tests:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 3000
  ReadTimeout: 60000
```

You need to set "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in the
incoming request. Chrome does not do this by default
apparently, but I was able to test with curl, e.g.

```
$ curl -v -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" \
  -F "file=@mylarg.iso" \
  localhost:9999/zuul/direct/file
```

The old proxy paths through the DispatcherServlet are still
available (for backwards compatibility and for convenience of
having the paths available at the root of the context path).

Comment: Ok, eyeballing the commit, it looks like traffic is routed through the DispatcherServlet by default.  If that is the case, I can leverage interceptors before hitting the ZuulController.

Comment: yes, assuming you mean http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Comment: One trick with this is if you are using a WebKit browser and standard JavaScript XMLRequest. It appears to not support Transfer-Encoding as a safe header.

Comment: This worked for me without the chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: I don't understand how this works with regards to the exposed endpoints. How can you have a single service handle normal rest and multipart on the same endpoint? for example, a user endpoint on http://api.foobar.com/user and the large picture upload on http://api.foobar.com/user/picture without it being http://api.foobar.com/zuul/user/picture?